# how to represent trees and their content in MySQL?

Tags: sql, mysql, database, database-design, tree

I need to be able to store something like this:
[image: Structure]

where the green is a `template` type, the gray is a `field container` type, and the white is `field`. (That being, a field has a label and some text, both mediumtext for simplicity; and a field container can store other field containers or text, and a template is a top-level field.)

Now, let's say I want to allow users to create any number of these structures, but it is unlikely to be more than say 10. And, of course, we need to be able to link data to it.

This is all to be able to store in a database an associative array that looks for the above like, in pseudo code:

```
my_template = {
  page_info => { description => 'hello!!!' },
  id => 0,
  content => { background_url => '12121.jpg', text => ...
}
```

Having an easy way to add a field to all data using the template when the template changes (say, we add a `keywords` to page_info) would be a big plus.

I can't figure this out at all, thanks a lot!

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL table structure question.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3486109/mysql-table-structure-question)

Comment: @OMG Ponies, no, because that doesn't cover how to store information about them, just the structure.

Comment: @AaronYodaiken, Have you solved this problem? How? It was always easy for me to build table-tree structure, but now I have a specific and similar problem. I want to save in db tables some structure that can be defined as View object from  MVC pattern.
for example:
t_view('id', 'path_to_file'), t_vars('id', 'var', 'view_id'); - these tables are defining single view block with it's variables. I need to generate multidimensional template, based on some View, each variable can be also View each variable ... and so on. And one template can extend another with re-defining some variable values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several different ways to store heirarchical data structures (trees) in MySQL. You can for example choose:

- Adjacency list
- Nested sets
- Path enumeration
- Closure table

See Bill Karwin's [presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/models-for-hierarchical-data) for more details on the pros and cons of each.

Comment: Thanks for these. I didn't know Bill Karwin, and there are some gems in his presentations.